# can't sorting properly in with gridview in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sorting, gridview

I want to sort my integer data, but I want to make it easier to read, like 1000000000 and I want it display 1,000,000,000  so I use this query;

```
format(col_name,0)
```

I tried to sort it with sort function in C# using gridview, and this is what happen when I tried to sort data2;

```
+================++================+
|     data1      |      data2      |
+================++================+
|     21,039,000 |               6 |
|     30,080,000 |           4,062 |
|    209,120,040 |          28,692 |
|    201,200,900 |           2,115 |
|      1,100,900 |          15,858 |
+================++================+
```

I think I made ​​a mistake because I use `format(col_name,0)`, but how can I fix it?

ps:I should change the question, because I'm actually trying to sort using gridview in c# and the result is like that, so at first I thought there was an error in mysql query, I can't use order by because I have more than one column to sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply order it by the name of the column and not the alias given since the original column is already an `INT`,

```
SELECT format(col_name,0) data
FROM   tableName
ORDER  BY col_name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2146d/2)

Comment: I think I should change the question, because I'm actually trying to sort using c# and the result is like that, so at first I thought there was an error in my query

Comment: if you have no column that is an int on the result set, you can still sort it using `LINQ`, example `var _results = GetList().OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Replace(",",""))).ToList();` where `GetList()` is a source of string. here's a screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rb34q.png

Comment: what is the data source of your gridview?

Comment: I use this to sort gridview; `sortedView = new DataView(dataset);
sortedView.Sort = "data2 Desc";
GridView1.DataSource = sortedView;
GridView1.DataBind();`